# artifactory local repo in maven project

Tags: maven, artifactory

I've setted artifactory in localhost (I'm trying on localhost before setting up my server), but when I use this repo in my maven project I can't retrieve my libs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Error message? How does your pom look like ? How have you setted up Artifactory ? How should i guess ?

Comment: Artifactory is installed on port 8081, and I can't receive any error message...
`<repository>
        <id>ClaudioStas</id>
        <name>ClaudioStas-releases</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/stas</url>
    </repository>
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Artifactory** provides you with a [**small utility**](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifacts+Resolution) that **generates** a **Maven settings** file based on the repositories configured in Artifactory and your selections; assuming your repositories are properly configured, this utility normally does a good job.

Answer (score 0):

Try (change id ClaudioStas to central):

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
```